# “type of expression is ambiguous without more context” using struct property as dictionary key

Tags: ios, swift

I am getting and exception:

> type of expression is ambiguous without more context

with following code:

```
struct Parameter { 
    static let Email = "email" 
    static let Password = "password" 
    static let IsFacebookUser = "isFacebookUser" 
}

let parameters : [String : AnyObject] = [Parameter.Email : email, Parameter.Password : password, Parameter.IsFacebookUser : false]
```

It's not accepting bool type and I don't want to change my data type.

Is there any issue in this code?

Comment: Show your Parameter declaration

Comment: Your code [works](https://www.evernote.com/l/AOy2YFe7leFHZZ9Pn-znlEcBmURO9PEm8mM) for me in a Playground.

Comment: Please show us the type of `email` and `password`.

Comment: let email = emailTextField.text
let password = passwordTextField.text

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your email and password are optional variables, you need to provide non-nil values to dictionary and, hence, should unwrap them by using `!` as suffix
Try this

```
let parameters : [String : AnyObject] = [Parameter.Email : email!, Parameter.Password : password!, Parameter.IsFacebookUser : false]
```

Alternatively, you can also do

```
email = emailTextField.text!
password = passwordTextField.text!
```

Also, replace your struct with enum.

```
enum Parameter: String {
    case Email: "emailKey"
    ...
}
```

and then use `Parameter.Email.rawValue` while creating dictionary.

Comment: I am using struct for Parameter, and problem is with boolean not with String...
struct Parameter {
    static let Email = "email"
    static let Password = "password"
    static let IsFacebookUser = "isFacebookUser"
}

Comment: still getting same issue...
let parameters : [String : AnyObject] = [Parameter.Email.rawValue : email, Parameter.Password.rawValue : password, Parameter.IsFacebookUser.rawValue : false]

Comment: @YasirAli: I assume you are the asker. Please try the solution described here adding the `!` to `email` and `password`. And let us know.

Comment: @YasirAli I think you are very new to Swift. You email and password are optional variables, you need to provide non-nil values to dictionary and hence should unwrap them by using `!` as suffix.

Comment: @SahilKapoor & appzYourLife: thanks adding ! suffix solved my problem, please edit your answer so that I can mark it accepted, also why should I use enum instead of struct?

Answer (score 0):

This type of error also comes when we pass the wrong parameters type to the struct object.